# Add an attribute to a selected node from the source XML

Tags: xslt, attributes

I am trying to add an attribute to a node selected from the source XML. My initial attempt is below, but I think I am misunderstanding the concept. Do I need to load the node into a variable first, or is there another way to do this?

**Source XML**

```
<root>
   <BigImage>
      <img alt="Flower" src="/flower.jpg" />
   </BigImage>
</root>
```

**Desired output**

```
<img alt="Flower" src="/flower.jpg" class="image-left" />
```

**Current *(incorrect)* XSLT**

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy-of select="./BigImage/node()" />
    <xsl:attribute name="class">image-left</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

**Current *(incorrect)* output**

```
<img alt="Flower" src="/flower.jpg" />
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and very short and simple solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="img">
   <img class="image-left">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   </img>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <BigImage>
        <img alt="Flower" src="/flower.jpg" />
    </BigImage>
</root>
```

**produces exactly the wanted, correct result**:

```
<img class="image-left" alt="Flower" src="/flower.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew I wasn't thinking in XSLT terms.